# Product of matrices representing rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I am trying to prove that, given $n\in \mathbb{N}$, the matrix $R_1=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\frac{2 \pi} {n}) &-\sin(\frac{2 \pi} {n}) \\
\sin(\frac{2 \pi} {n}) & \cos(\frac{2 \pi} {n})
\end{pmatrix}$
and the matrices $R_j=R_1^j \quad\forall j=0,1,\cdots, n-1$, then $R_jR_k=R_{(j+k) \pmod n} $. I have already showed that,by using the trigonometric identities for the sum of angles, $R_j$ represents a rotation of anngle $\frac{2 \pi j} {n} $. Moreover, by the properties of rotations, $R_jR_k=R_{\frac{2\pi(j+k)}{n}}$  But, at this point, I don't know how to conclude the desired equality. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: Check that $R_{j} = R_{j+2\pi}$.

Comment: Ok, I understand the use of the periodicity, then: $R_jR_k=R_{\frac{2\pi(j+k)}{n}+2\pi}=R_{\frac{2\pi(j+k+n)}{n}}$, but I don't get how to obtain $R_{(j+k)modn}$.

Comment: Using $\pi$ in the index only confuses things cause nowhere is that notation defined. You just have $R_1$ and powers of that matrix. The main thing you have to show is that $(R_1)^j$ is like $R_1$ but for angle $j2\pi/n$ and hence that $(R_1)^n=I$. The result for $R_jR_k$ follows from addition of exponents.

Comment: Suggestion: _Don't_ restrict yourself to rational multiples of $2\pi$. That is, for real $\theta$, _start_ by considering the matrices $$R_\theta:=\left[\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{array}\right]$$and using trig identities to show $R_\theta R_\phi = R_{\theta+\phi}$ for all real $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Comment: @CharlesJA You and manlet_hunter have made incorrect statements. The correct fact here is that $R_jR_k = R_{j + k} \neq R_{\frac{2\pi(j+k)}{n}}$. Similarly, $R_j = R_{j + n} \neq R_{j + 2\pi}$.